# server side java socket programming for reading http POST messages

Tags: http, post, inputstream, serversocket, is-empty

I have some problem with Socket Input Stream for reading the post messages. When the client sends a POST http message to server, the server can't read the line between the http header and footer and it takes a lot of time. I think it can't read the empty line and it's in an infinite loop. What do you think?

```
Scanner netInput = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
String s = "";
while (this.netInput.hasNextLine()) {
                    s = this.netInput.nextLine();
                    message += s + "\n";
                    System.out.println("*" + s);
                }
```